# Can I update an image in the drawable directory from code?

Tags: android

I have a picture in res/drawable directory: res/drawable/picture.jpeg.

Can I dynamically update this picture.jpeg from code? i.e. I want to use another picture to replace this picture in the drawable directory dynamically.

If I can, what path should I use to access the picture? Should I use "res/drawable/picture.jpeg"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I dynamically update this
>   picture.jpeg from code?

No. Resources are part of the signed APK file and cannot be modified at runtime, other than by shipping an updated APK to your users.